# What frameworks/technology stack should I use for my Java project?

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm about to start a new project in my organization and it must be done using Java and other open source technologies that can be consumed using Java (this is, they provide a Java or at least a RESTful api). The project is mid-size and will start with few users, like 10, but it should be constructed to be scalable from time and support more users, like 100.

This is the current technologies and frameworks alternatives I have in mind:

Database:

- MySQL 5.6
- Postgres 9.3

Data Access:

- Hibernate 4 (no JPA)
- JPA 2.1/Hibernate 4
- MyBatis

Dependency Injection framework, to create Service layer and probably enhance other layers like Dao or Presentation:

- Manual, no framework
- Spring core
- CDI (Context Dependency Injection)
- Guice (I just heard of it and I wanna try it out, but not sure)

Web UI:

- Spring MVC
- JSF
- GWT
- Struts 2
- AngularJS
- Web Component

Please provide recommendations. I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on meta, if anywhere?

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought so but the answer is too technical oriented to be on meta :)

Comment: I dunno, I guess I believe MSO is for SO stuff, so reference material for SO belongs there, regardless of technicality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to note, these questions fall into two categories

- **Too Broad**. There are lot of stuff to explain, examples to provide, and what's even more difficult: provide an example that works and satisfies the minimal requirements of most of readers.
- **Primarily Opinion-Based**. There are lot of people with different expertise out there that have tried some of almost all these frameworks and have conclusions that depends on lot of factors. For example: the size of the project, the ability to develop code faster, the ability to develop reliable solution, the budget of the project, how much expertise the team have in Java or in other related technologies, the time to spend learning the technology/framework... and more. And with this basis, and why not to say, with many tastes around, people will show you gold of some technologies and rant about others.

With the points explained above, you can directly infer that **there is no specific answer**. But there are alternatives to define what you should use.

- Define your [quality attributes](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/architecture/start/reasoning.cfm). This is, gather the relevant non-functional requirements that the [project stakeholders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_stakeholder) have to this new app, system, ecosystem or whatever size your project has. Some of them may be in this form:

  - The application must support lot of users in business hours time. This is, 8 a.m. - 5 p.m.
  - The application should have a Help Me option per page.
  - The application must support English and Spanish.
  - Nobody can use the application unless is logged. All actions performed by the user should be monitored.

  It would be better if you also group them by category. Here's a [list of system quality attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes).
- Once you have your quality attributes and a description for each, you prioritize them with help of the stakeholders and will have a small set of them. These would be the requirements the architecture must fulfill or else the project will be a failure (this depends on specific cases of the project, but usually this is what happens).
- With the set of quality attributes to fulfill, you may start refining them and specifying metrics for each. Metrics are necessary in software architecture because they provide a way to measure the software, which you will use to qualify and evaluate a technology or set of technologies. Only with the qualification (in numbers) you and other people can check the results and provide a conclusion per technology.
- With the quality attributes and metrics defined, you can establish a test suite that can help you provide values for the metrics and help you to evaluate and confront frameworks objectively. This is similar to establish a kickboxing ring and put two frameworks against each other. The rules are defined, and *it will be a single winner* (this can vary depending on your requirements as well).

  **Important**: Not all the test cases should be programmatic based. For example, you may have a quality attribute associated with [modifiability](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modifiability) of the application: *how easy is to add Foo feature with the current code base*, which you will measure by adding *Foo* to the current design you have and add an ordinal qualification from *Piece of Cake* to *Rocket Science* (or 0 to 5 to be more understandable).
- Start designing and implementing a proof of concept using the frameworks/technologies defined and then execute your test suite against it. You have to keep in mind that this framework/technology and the design you're doing must have to support the selected quality attributes, so try to make them shine for the tests (and then they will shine in the real app).
- Once you executed your test suite against the framework, annotate the results per framework/technology. At the end, you will have a sort of checklist and the results for each of them, and it will be easier to make a choice.

I'll provide an example of this for Data Access frameworks shown above:

> Data Access:
>
> - Hibernate 4 (no JPA)
> - JPA 2.1/Hibernate 4
> - MyBatis

Determine the quality attributes. For example purposes, we will only have a single category: Performance.

- Performance:

  - The app should process 20 000 Foo transactions under normal conditions.
  - The app should provide search results for Foo entity in less than 3 seconds under normal conditions.

The metrics:

- Performance:

  - Time to insert 20 000 in Foo table.
  - Time to delete 20 000 in Foo table.
  - Time to retrieve 20 000 results from Foo table.

Test suite:

- Performance:

  - Insert 20 000 in Foo table.
  - Delete 20 000 from Foo table. One by one.
  - Time to retrieve 20 000 results from Foo table.

Considerations for tests (this is specific for test case):

- `Foo` table has a relationship with `FooDetail` and `FooStatusHistory`. Every time we insert a row in `Foo` table, we have to insert 3 rows in `FooDetail` and 2 in `FooStatusHistory`.
- Every time we retrieve `Foo`, we also have to retrieve the associated `FooDetail` and the *last* `FooStatusHistory` associated with `Foo`.
- `Foo` table will start with 20 000 rows. `FooDetail` will start with 3 rows per `Foo` row. `FooStatusHistory` will start with 2 rows per `Foo` row.

Then, after designing, implementing and performing the tests using the frameworks in my test environment:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bits
- JVM: Java SE 8 u20
- Database: MySQL 5.6

Results in seconds (average after 10 runs):

```
                                    Hibernate 4    JPA 2.1/Hibernate 4    MyBatis

- Insert 200 000 in Foo table.        120.42              125.14           94.47
- Delete 200 000 from Foo table.
  One by one.                         120.05              128.41           55.13
- Time to retrieve 200 000 results
  from Foo table.                      36.12               34.24            4.01
```